# Get yocto to build with TARGET_FPU=hardfp

Tags: floating-point, yocto, openembedded

I am building a yocto based linux and I have a problem with building for hard floating point.

I have tried various TUNE_FEATURES from [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/conf/machine/include/tune-cortexa9.inc) but everytime I run bitbake it says the Build Configuration is TARGET_FPU="softfp".

How do I force yocto to build with hardfp, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had the `DEFAULTTUNE` variable not being set due to a uneffective override.
`DEFAULTTUNE` seems to be the variable responsible for setting hardfp/softfp.

`bitbake -e > out.txt` was a great help.